# How to intercept i18n prefix change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

We're using i18n in nuxt with prefix strategy.

Current behavior is that when user goes to page `/` it redirects to `/en`, because 'en' is the default locale.

I want to intercept i18n redirect (prefix change) with own custom logic, so that before it redirects to default locale it reads the locale stored in local storage and, if it exists, i18n should use that stored locale instead the default locale. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onBeforeLanguageSwitch` callback.

From the official [documentation](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/callbacks#onbeforelanguageswitch)

> Called before the app's locale is switched. Can be used to override the new locale by returning a new locale code.

So you could create a plugin that handles the logic for you. For example (as in the official [documentation](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/callbacks#usage)):

`/plugins/i18n.js`:

```js
export default function ({ app }) {
  // onBeforeLanguageSwitch called right before setting a new locale
  app.i18n.onBeforeLanguageSwitch = (oldLocale, newLocale, isInitialSetup, context) => {
    console.log(oldLocale, newLocale, isInitialSetup)
  }
  // onLanguageSwitched called right after a new locale has been set
  app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = (oldLocale, newLocale) => {
    console.log(oldLocale, newLocale)
  }
}
```

Comment: This callback seems to work on client side, but not when I load the page for the first time.

Comment: How have you registered the plugin?

Comment: Same as in the docs. I tried with `mode: 'server'` but it didn't change anything.